# Form bean scopes in struts

Tags: struts

When we say we have declared our form bean in session scope, few questions arise :
NOTE : A session is per client.
Assumptions :
a)Form bean object is in session.
b)In reset() method, we access the fields of form bean object, that is there in session.

Q-1) When is this session created and destroyed ?
  Q-2) Will reset() method will be called for each user request? Is yes, then we usually reset the field values in reset(), then how come these values will be available throughout session ? 
  Q-3)are request scope attribute values are available after validate() method ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The container is responsible for session management.
2. For each request to an action that uses a given form. Because usually fields aren't reset; it's mostly to deal with checkbox defaults, although there are other uses.
3. Of course; otherwise the values wouldn't be available in the action.